# why do i get nullpointerexeption?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dao, bufferedreader

```
class DAOBilTextFile implements DAOBil {
private ArrayList<DTOBil> dtoBilar;


public DTOBil dtobil;


public DAOBilTextFile() {
 dtoBilar = new ArrayList<DTOBil>();   
 Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
BufferedReader reader = null;


try {
        try{
        reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("databilar.txt"), charset);

        String line = null;
        DTOBil bil = null;
         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                 //tar in line och lägger in den i en array med hjälp av ; för att splitta datat
                 String strBilar[] = line.split(";");
                bil = new DTOBil(strBilar[0], strBilar[1], strBilar[2], strBilar[3]);
                //lägger till bil i arraylistan
                dtoBilar.add(bil);
             }reader.close();//this line is the error!

    }finally{
        reader.close();
        }} catch (IOException ioexp) {
        System.out.println(ioexp.getMessage());
    }




}

@Override
public void create(DTOBil dtobil) {
     Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    //klasser för att skriva till textfil
    BufferedWriter writer = null;


        try {
        writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("databilar.txt"), charset, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        writer.write(dtobil.getRegnr() + ";"
                    + dtobil.getMarke() + ";"
                    + dtobil.getModell() + ";"
                    + dtobil.getsokVag());
            writer.newLine();
            System.out.println("La till en bil");
            writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ioexp) {
       System.out.println(ioexp.getMessage());
     }
}
```

I get a "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at swing.labb3.DAOBilTextFile.(DAOBilTextFile.java:50)" 
but why? i don't understand? and my friend has done the exact same thing and his code works....
This isn't all of the code, but I've placed line 50 in the comments.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: }finally{
            reader.close();

Comment: Add `catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}` for inner try block to see errors why reader is null. Probably there some are problems with reading a file.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with java - can reader withstand being closed twice?

Comment: it didnt matter if i removed the close that's before the finally line. it didn't help.
But reader gets data at "reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("databilar.txt"), charset);
            
            String line = null;
            DTOBil bil = null;
             while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){"
and as i said, my friend did this code aswell, i just wrote as he did. :S

Comment: You got an error (and exception) creating the reader, so "reader" never got set.  When the finally clause was executed, the attempt to close a null pointer created a second exception.  If you look at the COMPLETE exception listing I'd be willing to bet that the original exception is listed farther down -- it will tell you why the `newBufferedReader` op failed.

Comment: Hint:  Scatter some `System.out.println` calls through the code.  Likely you never get past the `newBufferedReader` call.

Comment: @Alexey - There should be no need to add the catch/println -- the original exception is probably printed farther down in the existing exception trace info.

Answer (score 2):

Seemingly, you're missing the `databilar.txt` file, so the `newBufferedReader` call throws an `IOException`. So it diverts to the finally block and tries to close the reader, but since the reader was not set by the `newBufferedReader` call it is still `null`, and the attempt to close it throws a `NullPointerException`. In the finally block, you need a test for that:

```
} finally {
    if (reader != null) reader.close();
}
```

Then it will be able to harmlessly exit that finally block and get to the IOException catcher in the outer try block.

But the biggest problem is that it can't find the file.

Comment: okey, but doesnt java create that textfile or do i have to create it for my sellf?:s

Comment: @user2064844: I'd assumed it was a file you already had. I see now you have a method to create it, but because it is an instance method you can't call it until the object is created, but it is the object's constructor which tries to read it. So you need to either refactor the code (perhaps providing another constructor so you can create a blank one of those objects without a file) in order to run the file creation code first, or make the file yourself.